# Run MATLAB program hourly in specific times

Tags: matlab, timer

I have written a timer in MATLAB to run a specific function hourly:

```
function timertest
t = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', 'Period', 3600);
t.TimerFcn = {@my_callback_fcn};
start(t);

function my_callback_fcn(handles,~)
handles;
disp('test');
```

I want to add a property into `timer` function to run this program hourly as follows (hh:mm:ss):

- 01:01:00
- 02:01:00
- 03:01:00
- ...
- ...
- 23:01:00
- 00:01:00

For instance, if I run the program at 17:45:00, the program must wait until 18:01:00 to be executed. I mean, run hourly in the above mentioned time slots.
I am struggling to how can I add this property into `timer` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `StartDelay` property of the `Timer` class:

> Number greater than or equal to *0* that specifies the delay, in
>   seconds, between the start of the timer and the first execution of the
>   function specified in *TimerFcn*. When *Running = 'on'*, *StartDelay* is
>   read only.
>
> **Default:** 0

All you have to do is to set a `Period` of one hour (`3600` seconds) between each execution of the `TimerFcn` and compute the correct `StartDelay` value, which must be equal to the upcoming hour and 1 minute in respect of the current time. Here is an example:

```
function timertest()
    [~,m,s] = hms(datetime('now'));
    sd = (60 * (60 - m)) + (60 - s);

    t = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',3600,'StartDelay',sd);
    t.TimerFcn = @my_callback_fcn;

    start(t);
end

function my_callback_fcn(obj,evt) %#ok<INUSD>
    disp('Tick!');
end
```

Once the start delay has been properly defined, every tick will be fired at `HH:01`.

Answer (score 1):

use clock:

"c = clock returns a six-element date vector containing the current date and time in decimal form:

[year month day hour minute seconds]

The clock function calculates the current date and time from the system time."

So you can easily find the difference between 'now' and the next time you want the program to run (in seconds); then use the StartDelay feature of timer.

```
c=clock
delay= 60*(60-c[5])+60-c[6]
t=timer
t.startdelay = delay
```

sources:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clock.html

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop